# Python- how to get one method's argument value inside another method

Tags: python

I have the below codes

```
def bar(foo):
    # How can I access the value of 'is_prod' here??

def foo(config: dict):
    bar(foo)
    
foo({'is_prod': True})
```

I passed a method `foo` into another method `bar`, `foo` has input variable `config`, how can I access the value of that inside `bar`?

Comment: You're calling `bar` with the function `foo` is that intentional?

Comment: add the config parameter (or just a bool for is_pros) `to `bar`, and pass it along when you call it inside `foo`.

Comment: You have to be explicit. Passing in a function object does not pass in the namespace of a particular function call...

Comment: If you're trying to determine if this file should run in `is_prod` or `is_dev` mode, you should use environment variables. For example, load an env var called `export APP_ENVIRONMENT=Is_Prod`. Now inside your function you can check with `os.getenv("APP_ENVIRONMENT") == 'Is_Prod'`

Answer (score 0):

You could just pass the same parameter from `foo` as additional parameter to `bar`.

Solution "quick and simple":

```
def bar(foo, config: dict):
    # now you have access to the same config dictionary that was passsed to foo function below.
    print(config['is_prod'])

def foo(config: dict):
    bar(foo, config)
    
foo({'is_prod': True})
```

Note: If you need more parameters, there are python syntax tricks that could help you as well, so that you don't need to repeat a lot of variables. Or just put them in the dictionary.

More organized:

If `config` is some kind of *state* that you want to access from different place, then maybe it's worth using a class.

Config is an attribute given in constructor, and both foo and bar are member methods, so they can both access the config instance.